# StringBuilder - Should only Append and AppendLine be used without combining strings in arguments?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have started to use `StringBuilder` as I hear it's much more optimized when it comes to outputting strings.

My question is regarding the use of `+` as strings are immutable and when you add them together it allocates a new string.

If I use this operator in the arguments for the `StringBuilder.Append` function, I assume it will essentially have the same overhead.

For example:

```
string animal1 = "dog";
string animal2 = "cat";

stringBuilder.Append("Today I saw a " + animal1 + " and " + animal2);
```

My guess is that this could concatenate these texts together allocating memory anyway.

I assume the more efficient (albeit verbose) way to do this would be:

```
stringBuilder.Append("Today I saw a");
stringBuilder.Append(animal1);
stringBuilder.Append(" and ");
stringBuilder.Append(animal2);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Why not use [AppendFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat?view=netframework-4.7.2)? `stringBuilder.AppendFormat("Today I saw a {0} and {1}", animal1, animal2);`

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in the second example, as you miss a space between "Today I saw a" and `animal1`. Unless you are doing this in an excessive way (within a loop with many iterations) you'll probably find no measurable difference, so your best bet is probably to aim for readability.

```
$"Today I saw a {animal1} and a {animal2}"
```

Yes, I added an `a` before the second animal too :) I'm not handling cases for "an" though.

You also have the option of using `AppendFormat` if you want to be less verbose with all those appends...

```
stringBuilder.AppendFormat("Today I saw a {0} and a {1}", animal1, animal2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating strings like that allocates the memory for a new string, just to have it appended to your `StringBuilder`, which is just wasteful. As you noted, you should just explicitly `Append` them instead.